# Values showing on both x-axes even though plt.subplots(sharex = True)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am working with a small data set on water consumption. I have two subplots, and I am telling them to share their x-axes, however, the graphs are not representing this fact. I am able to use plt.subplots(sharex = True) for plots when not using this data set, which leads me to wonder if this is an issue between the pandas and matplotlib libraries. My code is simple and below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Source = https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Environment/Water-Consumption-In-The-New-York-City/ia2d-e54m

data_loc = 'D:\CSVs\Water_Consumption_In_The_New_York_City.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data_loc, parse_dates=True)
#editing the population data to be per million
df['New York City Population'] = df['New York City Population']/1000000

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(8,5), sharex = True)
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax1.plot(df['Year'], df['NYC Consumption(Million gallons per day)'])
ax1.legend(['Water Consumption (Million Gallons per Day)'])

ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
ax2.plot(df['Year'], df['New York City Population'], color='red')
ax2.legend(['Population (In Millions)'])
plt.xlabel('Year')

plt.suptitle('NYC Water Consumption Data', size = 15)
plt.show()
```

This code produces these graphs, which do not share one x-axis:

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(8,5), sharex = True)
```

is one row and two columns so sharex does not make sense.

And ax1, ax2 are the subplots so initialising them again is not necessary

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_loc = 'D:\CSVs\Water_Consumption_In_The_New_York_City.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data_loc, parse_dates=True)
#editing the population data to be per million
df['New York City Population'] = df['New York City Population']/1000000

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(8,5), sharex = True)
ax1.plot(df['Year'], df['NYC Consumption(Million gallons per day)'])
ax1.legend(['Water Consumption (Million Gallons per Day)'])

ax2.plot(df['Year'], df['New York City Population'], color='red')
ax2.legend(['Population (In Millions)'])
plt.xlabel('Year')

plt.suptitle('NYC Water Consumption Data', size = 15)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks much, initializing them twice was the cause of the issue. Appreciated!